# Can't use $near with String error in node express

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I am getting error "**Can't use $near with String error in node express**" when we find records basis on longitude and latitude with maxDistance.

following is code, I am using:-

1-schema code:-

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
 Schema = mongoose.Schema;


var dtSchema = new Schema({
    name:String,
    date: {type: Date, default: Date.now},
    location: { type: String, coordinates: [Number] },
    category:String   
});

//dtSchema.index({location: '2dsphere'});

module.exports = mongoose.model('places', dtSchema);
```

2-server.js code for fetch records

```
app.get('/location/:lon/:lat', function(req, res) {
   console.log(req.params.lon);
   console.log(req.params.lat);
   location.find({location:
       { $near:
          {
            $geometry: { type: "Point",  coordinates: [req.params.lon, req.params.lat ] },
            $maxDistance: 5000
          }
       }}, function(err, places) {

        if(!err){

            res.send('({"records":' + JSON.stringify(places) + '});');
        }
        else{
            console.log(err);
            res.send("error coming")
        }
    }); 


 });
```

**parameter sending URL**

http://localhost:4700/location/-73.9667/40.78

when we execute code and hit above URL. I found error "Can't use $near with String error in node express"

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem a while ago. The error is in the schema declaration.

```js
var dtSchema = new Schema({
    name:String,
    date: {type: Date, default: Date.now},
    location: { 
      type: {
        type: String
      }, 
      coordinates: [Number] 
    },
    category:String   
});
```

Answer (score 0):

db.location.aggregate([ { "$geoNear": { "near": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [72.4468035,23.032069] }, "maxDistance": 500, "spherical": true, "distanceField": "distance" } } ])

Comment: below mention query is orking in mongo shell but not working with mongoose .Please help me  short out the issue


db.location.find({ location: { $nearSphere: { $geometry: { type: "Point", coordinates: [ -73.93414657, 40.82302903 ] }, $maxDistance:500 } } })

Comment: i m not geeting that why this query not working in mongoose

Comment: can you give me example which store in your location collection??

Comment: in my query you have to put   spherical: true, when running it

Comment: db.location.aggregate([
        {
            "$geoNear": {
                "near": {                                                                            
                    "type": "Point",
                    "coordinates": [72.4468035,23.032069]
                },
                "maxDistance": 500,
                "spherical": true,
                 "distanceField": "distance"
               }
        }
     
    ])

Comment: example of my collection:
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("55cba2476c522cafdb053f26"), 
    "location" : {
        "coordinates" : [
            -73.9419856, 
            40.5990429
        ], 
        "type" : "Point"
    }, 
    "name" : "Perry'S Restaurant"
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("55cba2476c522cafdb053f27"), 
    "location" : {
        "coordinates" : [
            -73.97213099999999, 
            40.755833
        ], 
        "type" : "Point"
    }, 
    "name" : "San Martin"
}

Comment: db.location.aggregate([ { "$geoNear": { "near": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [72.4468035,23.032069] }, "maxDistance": 500, "spherical": true, "distanceField": "distance" } } ])

 i am  using "distanceField": "distance" same query above query . it executed without error but not return matched records. in my collection I am not using "distance". what will be pass in this case.

Comment: try to decrease maxDistance value then you get proper result in your output.

Comment: refer above link

Comment: its working on mongo shell properly but not working  with monggose.

Answer (score 0):

The schema for geoNear should be

```
loc: {
 type: {
  type: String, 
  enum: ["Point"], 
 },
 coordinates: {
  type: [Number],
  index: "2dsphere",
  // 2dSphere supports queries that calculate geometries on an 
  // earth like sphere
  },
},
```